# Priority 5 block baked. How to analyse what happened here?

Tags: blockchain, block

Block BLznpNup33vnSbByistRGsjsGZvYu6dy89zwMY8x4Z3rB9j53Ys at block level [367813](https://tzscan.io/heads?level=367813) was baked with priority 5 by Foundation Baker 1 and thus was baked roughly 7 min after the previous block. I've never seen this before. Are there ways to analyse what happened here and if so, what is the procedure to perform such an analysis?

Comment: It seems natural to keep seeing higher priorities the longer you watch. Eventually there will be a run of bad luck worse than ever before.

Comment: TzScan only provides the priority 0 baker and the baker with the priority that eventually baked the block. I'm curious what happened in between and my question is related to how to carry out a deeper analysis. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @MarcB that's not true, tzscan will show all the uncles their nodes have seen.

Comment: Ok, didn’t know that. Where do I find this information?